# Escaping @ in Windows environment variable

Tags: windows, batch-file, environment-variables

I have the following lines in a bat file:

```
SET LIB="C:\tools\oracle\main\ojdbc8.jar"
SET DRIVER="Java::oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
SET CONN="jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:1521/XE"

logstash -f logstash.conf
```

The two first SETs work fine, but the logstash program complains that the CONN variable is not a valid URI. I tried to put a `^` before the `@` to escape it, but the problem persists. How can this be fixed?

Comment: I'm not familiar with what you're trying to do, but isn't the standard convention more like `protocol://user:password@host:port/path`?

Comment: Nor do you need to escape `@`. It only has special meaning if it becomes the first character in a line. If it did need to be escaped, which it doesn't, then putting it in quotes, as you did, would be sufficient.

Comment: You should be using this syntax, `Set "VarName=StringValue"`, then you should doublequote `%VarName%` if/as required in any subsequent commands which use it.

Comment: @Compo your solution worked, write it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are currently including doublequotes as part of the variable value strings. I would recommend instead using the following syntax when `set`ting your variables:

```
Set "VarName=StringValue"
```

*You would then doublequote `%VarName%` if/as required in any subsequent commands which use it*.

In your provided example, I'd suggest that you therefore use:

```bat
Set "LIB=C:\tools\oracle\main\ojdbc8.jar"
Set "DRIVER=Java::oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
Set "CONN=jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:1521/XE"
```

And make independent decisions within your script on whether to use:

1. `%LIB%`, `%DRIVER%` or `%CONN%`
2. `"%LIB%"`, `"%DRIVER%"` or `"%CONN%"`
3. `!LIB!`, `!DRIVER!` or `!CONN!`            - *(delayed expansion)*
4. `"!LIB!"`, `"!DRIVER!"` or `"!CONN!"`  - *(delayed expansion)*